# MS Access Loop to update Web Pages stuck on first record

Tags: loops, html

Access 2016: The code works and is really sweet! However it loops only for the first record. I've spent 2 days moving/adding Loop code around with no success.

When I get it to work: Browser = False. I plan to add a counter to see the update process.

Also I may need to add a Loop Pause if eBay's servers can't process the data fast enough?

Code: (I've left a few lines out... but the main code is good)

```
Private Sub ReviseSKUAll_Click()
Dim btnUpdate As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intI As Integer
Dim skuNumber As Object
Dim IE As Object
Set dbs = CurrentDb
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
'Begin Loop
strSQL = "SELECT Inventory.[Item ID] FROM Inventory"
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
'If the recordset is empty, exit.
If rst.EOF Then Exit Sub
intI = intI + 1
 'intI = 1
 rst.MoveLast
 rst.MoveFirst
 With rst
Do Until .EOF
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'--------------------------------------------
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Height = 1000
    .Width = 1250
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate " ""

Do While .Busy Or Not .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until .Document.ReadyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop

 Set AllHyperlinks = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
   For Each hyper_link In AllHyperlinks
   If hyper_link.innerText = "editpane_skuNumber" Then
      hyper_link.Click
   Exit For
   End If
   Next
  'eBays Page Sku info
  '">


 Call .Document.getElementById("editpane_skuNumber").setAttribute("value", 
 (Nz([CustomLabelCombine]) & "   " & (Nz("Location" & "   " & [Location]) 
     & "    " & (Nz("Bin" & " " & [Bin])))))
  Set AllHyperlinks = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
  Set AllHyperlinks = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
  For Each hyper_link In AllHyperlinks
  If hyper_link.innerText = "pbtn" Then
     hyper_link.Click
  Exit For
  End If
  Next
  End With

  With IE.Document
  'eBays Update Listing Button Push
  '<input class="pbtn" type="button" value="Update listing" fn="pub">
  Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
  For Each e In elems
  If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Update listing") Then
      e.Click

  Exit For
  End If
  Next e
  IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
   'eBays Close Listing Button Push
   '<input class="pbtn" type="button" value="Close" fn="clsRv">
   '----------------------------------------------------------------------

  'End Loop
   rst.MoveNext
   End With
   Loop
   End With
   '----------------------------------------------------------------------
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code here and it looks like it should loop through the `rst` RecordSet variable without an issue.  I even created a new database application, created a table named "Inventory" and gave it a field named "[Item ID]", and then cut and pasted your code above into the click event for a button on a form, and I seemed to be able to run through the overall `Do Until .EOF` loop without a problem!?!

However, the full code obviously hasn't been provided here to test it, because the code above does NOT show what is happening with each individual `[Item ID]` record from the `rst` recordset variable.  Also, the Navigate URL for IE is missing, so when I test this code, I'm not sure I'm doing the exact same things that you are. But, from my tests in Access, it DOES loop through all the records in the Inventory table when you call `rst.MoveNext` at the bottom of the over all `Do Until .EOF` loop.  So, without more information or the complete code, a couple of things that come to mind:

1. Is it possible that you're hitting an error in the code somewhere here that is causing this code to break the overall `Do Until` loop and/or sub?  For example, if you have called `SetWarnings = false` (in a previous sub even) and you hit an error, you will not see an error message here and the code will fail silently, because warnings are turned off.
2. Otherwise, I suspect that whatever is causing the problem is in the missing code that has not been provided here.  You could always create a new sub, and cut and paste bits of the code at a time to find out exactly where this error is actually occurring.  That would be my next step, if you don't want to provide the full code here.

Anyway, I hope this all makes sense and it is helpful to you.  But if you have any questions about this answer, please feel free to message me or comment here and I will do my best to help out!

Comment: GeoffreyG, You have been very helpful and given me a path that I had not thought about.   I hope you understand i'm not able to provide all of the code publicly because that could possible allow all of my eBay listings to be compromised.  Thank You, Bill

Comment: Just in case anyone has a similar issue, I was able to make it Loop with    `While Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount]` and `Me.Recordset.MoveNext`  However I will need to ad a pause between Loops, as I get an eBay webpage error after 10 or so updated pages. Thanks again GeoffreyG  for your help.